# Cannot read script js file in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, netbeans

I am trying to insert script in the body of my HTML:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myFunction.js"></script>
```

Probably the problem is the path, but I am not able to find my error, I change it 100 of the times, here is my "myFunction.js":

```
        function myFunction() {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var tamano = 0;
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        console.log(tr.length);
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[7];
        //console.log(td);
        if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tamano = tamano +1;
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        }
        }
        var list = document.getElementById("capa");   // Get the <ul> element with id="myList"
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]); 
        console.log(tamano);
        var capa = document.getElementById("capa");
        var h1 = document.createElement("p");
        h1.innerHTML = tamano;
        capa.appendChild(h1);

        }
```

And you can see here my project folder:

[image: Proyect folder]

Can you help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your file `myFunction.js` is inside the folder for backend resources, where your Java code can access. This file will be disabled for browser access because this isn't the place for your web files.

You have to move that file to `src/main/webapp` (file system) next to your JSP and HTML resources. Files in this folder, except for `WEB-INF` folder, are available through browsers. Do similar with  LOGO.png file as well.

Comment: Hi! I think the file is already out of the ".java" files, the java files are located into "Source Packages" and the html templates, js, and .png are located into the folder named "Other Sources" . I don't have any problem to load the LOGO.png file, my problem is just with the js.

Comment: `src/main/resources/` is the folder for files used by your Java code **only**, not for the web application. Web resources are not meant to go there, they should go in `src/main/webapp` as shown in https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/